# Mysql query to calculate hotel rate for different season (high, low) with room type

Tags: php, mysql

I have two following tables one is for hotel rates based on high, low season value and another is the for date range and season entry.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can i get the count of days in high season or low season with the total rate based on date entry.
I am using the following sql which is incomplete.

```
SELECT tbl_seasonal_range.start_dt,
       tbl_seasonal_range.end_dt,
       tbl_season.season,
       tbl_hotel.hotel_name FROM tbl_seasonal_range LEFT JOIN tbl_season ON tbl_season.id = tbl_seasonal_range.seasonid LEFT JOIN tbl_hotel ON tbl_hotel.id = tbl_seasonal_range.hotelid 

WHERE tbl_hotel.id IN (3) AND (tbl_seasonal_range.start_dt >= '2019-11-10' AND tbl_seasonal_range.start_dt <= '2019-11-14')OR 
                (tbl_seasonal_range.end_dt >= '2019-11-10' AND tbl_seasonal_range.end_dt <= '2019-11-14')
```

Can anybody guide me solve the query? Thanks

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Also, note that   `LEFT 
  JOIN h ... WHERE h.id IN/=` is the same as `INNER JOIN h...`

Comment: You can use outer join here in this particular type of situation